# How to find the "html/php page" of login and change details

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have buildup a website "http://digitalsolutionscare.com/localbantu" in which I used a plugin called "tourmaster". Now i want to change the login page details along with the redirection URL when i signin. The login page url is "http://digitalsolutionscare.com/localbantu/?tourmaster-login". Currently, its redirecting to the profile page but I want to change that to the homepage.

I have found the single page of login but it is not helpful.
Please help me find the exact code.

Below is the single page of login.php-

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying login page
     */
nocache_headers();

// reset password action
if( !empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'rp' ){
    list($rp_path) = explode('?', wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $rp_cookie = 'wp-resetpass-' . COOKIEHASH;

    if( isset($_GET['key']) ){
        $value = sprintf('%s:%s', wp_unslash($_GET['login']), wp_unslash($_GET['key']));
        setcookie($rp_cookie, $value, 0, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true);
        wp_safe_redirect(remove_query_arg(array('key')));
        exit;
    }

    if( isset($_COOKIE[$rp_cookie]) && 0 < strpos($_COOKIE[$rp_cookie], ':') ){
        list($rp_login, $rp_key) = explode(':', wp_unslash($_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ]), 2);
        $user = check_password_reset_key($rp_key, $rp_login);
        if( isset($_POST['pass1']) && !hash_equals($rp_key, $_POST['rp_key']) ){
            $user = false;
        }
    }else{
        $user = false;
    }

    if( !$user || is_wp_error($user) ){
        setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );

        if( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ){
            $rp_key_error = 'expired_key';
        }else{
            $rp_key_error = 'invalid_key';
        }
    }else{

        $errors = new WP_Error();
        if( isset($_POST['pass1']) && $_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'] ){
            $errors->add('password_reset_mismatch', esc_html__( 'The passwords do not match.', 'tourmaster'));
        }

        do_action('validate_password_reset', $errors, $user);

        if( (!$errors->get_error_code()) && isset($_POST['pass1']) && !empty($_POST['pass1']) ){
            reset_password($user, $_POST['pass1']);
            setcookie($rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true);
            $rp_success = true;
        }else{
            $rp_error = $errors->get_error_message();
        }
    }
} // // reset password action

get_header();

    echo '<div class="tourmaster-template-wrapper" >';
    echo '<div class="tourmaster-container" >';
    echo '<div class="tourmaster-page-content tourmaster-' . (empty($_GET['action'])? 'login': $_GET['action']) . '-template-content  tourmaster-item-pdlr" >';

    ///////////////////////////
    // login page
    ///////////////////////////
    if( empty($_GET['action']) ){
        if( !empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'login_incorrect' ){
            echo '<div class="tourmaster-notification-box tourmaster-failure" >';
            echo esc_html__('Invalid username, email address or incorrect password.', 'tourmaster');
            echo '</div>';
        }

        tourmaster_get_login_form();

    ///////////////////////////
    // lost password page
    ///////////////////////////
    }else if( $_GET['action'] == 'lostpassword' ){
        if( !empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'login_incorrect' ){
            echo '<div class="tourmaster-notification-box tourmaster-failure" >';
            echo esc_html__('Invalid username or email.', 'tourmaster');
            echo '</div>';
        }
?>
<form class="tourmaster-lost-password-form tourmaster-form-field tourmaster-with-border" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(network_site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post')); ?>" >
    <p class="tourmaster-lost-password-user">
        <label><?php echo esc_html__('Username or E-mail:', 'tourmaster'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="user_login" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php do_action('lostpassword_form'); ?>
    <p class="tourmaster-lost-password-submit" >
        <input type="submit" class="tourmaster-button" value="<?php echo esc_html__('Get New Password', 'tourmaster'); ?>" />
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="source"  value="tm" />
</form>
<?php

    ///////////////////////////
    // reset password page
    ///////////////////////////
    }else if( $_GET['action'] == 'rp' ){

        if( !empty($rp_key_error) ){
            echo '<div class="tourmaster-notification-box tourmaster-failure" >';
            if( $rp_key_error == 'invalid_key' ){
                esc_html_e('Your password reset link appears to be invalid. Please request a new link below.', 'tourmaster');
            }else if( $rp_key_error == 'expired_key' ){
                esc_html_e('Your password reset link has expired. Please request a new link below.', 'tourmaster');
            }
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<p><a href="' . add_query_arg(array('source'=>'tm'), wp_lostpassword_url()) . '" >';
            echo esc_html__('Forget Password?','tourmaster');
            echo '</a></p>';
        }else{

            if( !empty($rp_success) ){
                echo '<div class="tourmaster-notification-box" >';
                echo esc_html__('Your password has been reset.', 'tourmaster');
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<p><a href="' . tourmaster_get_template_url('login') . '" >';
                echo esc_html__('Sign in to your account.','tourmaster');
                echo '</a></p>';
            }else{
                //wp_enqueue_script('utils');
                wp_enqueue_script('user-profile');

                if( !empty($rp_error) ){
                    echo '<div class="tourmaster-notification-box tourmaster-failure" >' . $rp_error . '</div>';
                }

                $pre_generate_pass = wp_generate_password(16);
?>
<form class="tourmaster-reset-password-form tourmaster-form-field tourmaster-with-border" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
    <div class="tourmaster-reset-password-new" >
        <label><?php esc_html_e('New password', 'tourmaster') ?></label>
        <input name="pass1" id="pass1" class="input" type="password" value="" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr($pre_generate_pass); ?>" autocomplete="off" data-reveal="1" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
        <div id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite" ><?php esc_html_e('Strength indicator', 'tourmaster'); ?></div>
    </div>

    <p class="tourmaster-reset-password-confirm" >
        <label><?php esc_html_e('Confirm new password', 'tourmaster') ?></label>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" value="<?php echo esc_attr($pre_generate_pass); ?>" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>

    <p class="tourmaster-reset-password-hint"><?php echo wp_get_password_hint(); ?></p>

    <?php do_action( 'resetpass_form', $user ); ?>

    <p class="tourmaster-reset-password-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" class="tourmaster-button" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset Password'); ?>" />
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="rp_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_key ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr($rp_login); ?>" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
<?php
            }
        }

    }

    echo '</div>'; // tourmaster-page-content
    echo '</div>'; // tourmaster-container
    echo '</div>'; // tourmaster-template-wrapper

get_footer(); 

?>
```